# Init 3D Java array without exact size in Python

Tags: python, java, arrays

I want to init a 3D array in python without knowing the last dimension size.

This is what i have in Java:

```
lastUnionNeg = new int[numberOfVariables+1][3][];
```

I want to do the same in Python if it is possible.
I search a lot but i did not find any useful. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is a sample how to create 3D array:
`num_var = 5`
`last_union_neg = [[[0 for k in range(unknown_size)] for j in range(3)] for i in range(num_var+1)]`
for access and modify the elements of the 3D like other lists 
`last_union_neg[0][1][0] = 23`

Comment: Just use a nested list comprehension `last_union_neg = [[[] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(number_of_variables + 1)]` and then `list.append`. `last_union_neg[0][0].append(2)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to init array dimension in python, since it's more like a linked list. Just create your array like `my_array = []`. Then, you can append arrays in it : `my_array.append(another_array)` as many times as you want. Do it 3 times and you have your matrix.

Comment: If you `append` the same `list` 3 times you're going to have surprising results.